# search for literal hash character in solr query

Tags: solr

I cannot find any documentation on the solr website that indicates how to search for a string that contains a literal hash character inside it.

example:

`?q=id_number:723#52`

I've tried escaping the hash, `723\#52`, and HTML encoding it, `723%2352`, but the solr output shows that it cuts off at the hash symbol each time:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">400</int>
<int name="QTime">2</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="q">id_number:723</str>
</lst>
</lst>
```

Comment: did you try with quotes. id_number:"723#52"

Comment: interestingly enough, I just tried it again with the URL encoded value, `723%2352`, and it has worked a few times now - so I think that's correct, I must have made a mistake somewhere else.  Putting the value in quotes does not make it work for me when I'm passing it through PHP, so I think it was just a URL encoding issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because solr will tokenize the query using class solr.StandardTokenizer so # character will removed from query.   you can change the tokenizer for field type definition. 
In your case for field id_number change the filter class from `solr.StandardTokenizer` to `solr.WhiteSpaceTokenizer`

But doing this method will accept all other special character in the query (.:,etc)